# manipulating a firebase array in a angular material dialog

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-material

I have a firebase array of json objects **posts**  , which has some key-value pairs and a array , i am using ng-repeat to display these values and a material dialog to add comment . In the dialog i passed the post from ng-repeat and attached a controller to the dialog , but when i push the comments in the array it shows **property push is not defined for undefined** even though my array is initialized with a blank array
 here is my app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['firebase', 'ngMaterial']);
    app.factory("posts", ["$firebaseArray",
                    function ($firebaseArray) {
            // create a reference to the database location where we will store our data
            //var randomRoomId = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
            var ref = new Firebase('https://xxxxxxxxx.firebaseio.com/posts');

            // this uses AngularFire to create the synchronized array
            return $firebaseArray(ref);
            }
                                 ]);
    app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'posts', '$timeout', '$mdToast', '$mdDialog', function ($scope, $firebaseArray, posts, $timeout, $mdToast, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.posts = posts;
        $scope.post = {};
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.showForm = false;
        $timeout(function () {

            $scope.loading = false;
        }, 5000);

        $scope.createPost = function (post) {
            $scope.posts.$add({
                name: post.name,
                desc: post.desc,
                url: post.url,
                like: 0,
                dislike: 0,
                comments: []
            });
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
            $scope.post = {};
            $scope.showForm = false;
            $mdToast.show(
                $mdToast.simple()
                .textContent('Post Added !!')
                .position("top right")
                .hideDelay(3000)
            );
        };
        $scope.showAddForm = function () {
            $scope.showForm = true;
        };
        $scope.clearForm = function () {
            $scope.showForm = false;
            $scope.myForm.$setPristine();
            $scope.myForm.$setUntouched();
            $scope.post = {};
        };

        $scope.showDialog = function (post) {


            $mdDialog.show({

                templateUrl: 'dialogtemp.html',
                locals: {
                    post: post,
                    posts: $scope.posts

                },
                controller: DialogController
            });
        }

        function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, post, posts) {
            $scope.post = post;
            $scope.posts = posts;
            $scope.closeDialog = function () {
                $mdDialog.hide();
            };
            $scope.addComment = function () {

                $scope.post.comments.push({
                    "by": "jain",
                    "com": "heyy"
                });
                $scope.posts.$save($scope.post);
            };
        };

                }]);
```

Comment: Does your `$scope.post` has a comments key available already. If not, I think you should be initializing that as `$scope.post.comments = []` first.

Comment: $scope.post.comments is an array which is already initialized by [ ] , i initialized that while adding the post , please have a look on createPost()

Comment: yeah , that worked , i checked that if array is empty before pushing , and reasigned it with [ ] , thanks a lot !! :tada:  , but i fail to understand why did this error occur when i already assigned an empty array to it ?

Comment: it shouldn't be the case. please go through whole of your code. maybe you missed something. please do post when you find the cause

Comment: i read an article that firebase does not  store empty arrays , so even when i was removing my all comments , it removed [ ] and same error started popping up again , so basically i had to check it every time .

Comment: thanks for all your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that your `$scope.post` has not `comments` key defined yet. Try initializing it with an empty array first and then `push()`(of course with the nessesary checks). A simple example would be.

```
var file = {};file.comments = [];file.comments.push({text:"hello"});//no error
```

But this would give you error

```
var file = {};file.comments.push({text:"hello"});//error: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined(…)
```